# c++ can't convert int to char to int again

Tags: c++, debugging, variables

In main i have

```
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int loop = 50;
    for(int p1 =0; p1 <256; p1++){
    for(int p2 =0; p2 <256; p2++){  
    for(int da =0; da <256; da++){
```

Will loop until (p1,p2,da) = (255,255,255).

```
    char *RGBA = new char[4];
```

Dynamicaly alocate a 4 byte array for rgba color.

```
    int Catch = Encode(p1, p2, da, RGBA);
    if ((int)RGBA[3] != da)
    {
        cout << (int)RGBA[3] << " != " << da << endl;
    }
```

In the future Encode will actual encode but now it just makes RGBA = {p1,p1,da,da}

Then if RGBA[3] != da (which it should not print both)

```
    counter += 1;
    if(counter == loop)
    {
        cin.get();
        counter = 0;
        delete[] RGBA;
        RGBA = nullptr; 
    }

    }}}
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when i run the code for the first 100 loops it runs well but after that I get weird results like:

```
-128 != 128
-127 != 129
-126 != 130
-125 != 131
-124 != 132
-123 != 133
-122 != 134
-121 != 135
```

In Encode:

```
int Encode(int Pas1, int Pas2,int Data, char to_Store[4])
{
    to_Store[0] = Pas1;
    to_Store[1] = Pas2;
    to_Store[2] = Data;
    to_Store[3] = Data;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unspecified in Standard if `char` is a signed or unsigned type. Some implementations have char as signed, some as unsigned. Looks like yours is signed, so to support interval of 0 - 255 you need to use `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

char type has range [-128; 127] so when you trying to compare int(128) with char it casts to char and becames char(-128). You should use unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet your loop runs fine through 127, and then overflow happens. `char` is a signed data type, and when its high bit is set, it is considered negative. You should use `unsigned char` here.